# How can I reload my Vaadin project without getting the offline error?

Tags: maven, vaadin

I am practicing vaadin development, I began by first creating the project on vaadin start. I was able to run the project on localhost:8080. The issue is, the next time i tried t run the project in the browser, i am getting this message;

"You are offline

tutorial_1 requires an internet connection to work. You do not seem to have access to the server right now. Check your internet connection and try reloading the page to use the application."

can anyone help?

from the tutorial videos online, i looked at the ConnectionState in the code, but i don't really know what to update because i did not change anything.

Comment: Is the app still running?

Comment: yes the app is still running i am using intellij

Comment: The offline message is shown, when the app is not reachable at the given url...

Comment: I managed to solve this issue, it was caused by the link between the app and the mysql database i created. I deleted the original database through the terminal and created another one and i was able to access the app on port 8080